# New {object} vs {object} = new {object}

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was just wondering if there is any difference between the two different new object initializers or is it just syntactic sugar.

So  is:

```
Dim _StreamReader as New Streamreader(mystream)
```

and different to:

```
Dim _StreamReader as Streamreader = new streamreader(mystream)
```

Is there any difference under the hood? or are they both the same?  Which one do you prefer to use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In VB.NET, they're identical. The `As New` variant is canonical.

In VB6, their semantics actually differed (apart form the obvious fact that VB6 didn't allow assignments in declarations): the `As New` variant would create an object that could never be `Nothing`. Rather, the runtime would ensure that the object was always properly initialized before each access to it.

Answer (score 2):

These statements are identical.  Personally I prefer the "Dim x as New" syntax because it's more concise.  There is no reason for writing the same type name in the same statement when it doesn't make a programatic difference.  All it does is make you spend more time on the keyboard :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a VB guy, but as far as I can tell they're equivalent. According to [MSDN's description of the Dim statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx):

> If you do not specify datatype, the
>   variable takes the data type of
>   initializer. If neither datatype nor
>   initializer is present, by default,
>   the data type is Object Data Type. If
>   you specify both datatype and
>   initializer, the data type of
>   initializer must be convertible to
>   datatype.

I won't pass comment on preference, as I don't use VB (except when answering statements).